# How to move the suiteBar so its centered

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-foundation, css, branding

I'm having trouble moving the suiteBar using the margin:0 auto 0 auto; method. I'm trying to make the my sharepoint site's content centered no matter the monitor's screen size (adjusting the width of the browser as high as 2000px). No matter what I do the welcomeMenuBox stays to the right and not centered with the content.

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 Foundation if that helps any.

Comment: What do you have for CSS right now? There are actually three sections of DOM that would have to be moved: #suiteLinksBox, #welcomeMenuBox, and #suiteBarButtons. This won't be as easy as using `margin:0 auto;` on one element.

Comment: Relative to the suiteBar I have 

/* this is the top bar-Right */
#suiteBarRight{
 margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

I removed the div holding #suiteBarLeft. I understand that #suiteLinksBox, #welcomeMenuBox, and #suiteBarButtons fall under #suiteBarRight. I thought if I just modify #suiteBar (because the suiteBars are under this id) with margin: 0 auto I'll get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out (from what I observed). I added **margin:0 auto 0 auto;** in the BODY tag and set the width to my desired pixels with **!important** at the end. This literally (I can't believe they are thinking of including the non-formal definition of the word) centers everything including the suiteBar. The only issue I saw was that in IE8 (I think, if not lower) the suiteBar still took the whole width of the browser. Other than that it works.

Cheers!